# Angular directive does not update when $http completes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller

I'm having trouble getting a directive to update after a `$http` completes. The two solutions I've tried are setting a flag `$scope.ready` to true and using with ngIf on a parent container and using `$scope.$watch()` for my `data` object. The flag doesn't seem to work, though the `element.replaceWith('<h1>test</h1>');` does seem to work, just both `newVal` and `oldVal` are undefined.

```
<div ng-if="ready">
  <puzzle data="data"></puzzle>
</div>

//function
function myCtrl($scope, $http){
    $scope.ready = false;
    $scope.data = {};
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: './app/data/test1.json'
    })
    .then(function(res){
        $scope.ready = true;
        $scope.data = res.data;
        console.log($scope.data);
        //tried $scope.$apply() here, no success
    }, function(){
        console.error('err', arguments);
    })
}

//directive
function myDirective(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            data: '=',
            ready: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
             scope.$watch('data',function(newVal, oldVal){
                console.log(scope, element, attrs);
             }, true);

            element.replaceWith('<h1>test</h1>'); //this prints out
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Update how? You should use a template instead of `element.replaceWith` as well

Comment: @Phil This was a remnant from a fiddle i had found that in the current state of things was just sort of there to ensure the directive was running at all.

Comment: As you can see here, the directive should update without you having to do anything ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/WLzFp5zBX9TGb4ob4P11?p=preview

Comment: @Phil Hmm. I see. If that is bound through scope, why is the data attr in the html necessary?

Comment: Also, why is it available to the `template` string, but not in my link function..

Comment: It's bound through the isolate scope (`scope: {data: '='}`) which is assigned via the directive attribute. You should be able to access the data in the `link` function via `scope.data`. I've updated the Plunker